# iOS simulator largest image should

Tags: ios, view

I'm having problem in iOS simulator, the image is higher than it should. See the picture.

[image]

The correct thing.

[image]

Size of images:

@1x = 750x120

@2x = 1500x240

@3x = 2250x360

did not work, I did so:

```
    divAcoes.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    divAcoes.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "divInfo")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the proper contentMode for the UIImageView.
That can be done in your Storyboard/XIB with Scale Aspect Fill or in code

`imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill`

Comment: did not work, I did so:
`divAcoes.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "divInfo")!)
        divAcoes.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill`

Comment: That's because you use the pattern image from UIColor, that should be an UIImageView. Otherwise the UIColor(patternImage) will ever use the proper pixel aspect ratio I believe

Answer (score 0):

You can always inspect your interface in runtime by clicking the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in Xcode while running the app.

It's either you have UIImageView's Mode set wrong or its size/position is incorrect.